# What sort of plastic is this? What would you call this color scheme?

Tags: plastic

[image]

I saw this plastic on a baby changing station and was wondering what sort of plastic it was. It seems like injection molding plastic but I'm not sure which one and also what pepper color scheme that is.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really on-topic here. If it is on-topic, I would say that you need to describe what you are seeing in the picture. Also, the properties of plastics can change a lot depending on the additives used. It may be hard to give you a definitive answer. Have you already looked for a marking on it (typically in a triangle)?

Comment: We can't be sure from just a picture, but the most common material for these kinds of devices is high-density polyethylene (HDPE) it's also common on playgrounds, outdoor furniture, and household cutting boards.

Comment: @hazzey: I'd say the type of question is on-topic, but this specific question in current form is unanswerable - we can at best make some informed guesses; a (rather poor quality) photo is definitely insufficient to identify a plastic.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for a speckle additive or as this company(link below) refers to it as stone/granite/marble effect...Looks like a Granite type effect to me:

Here's a link:
[Plastic special effects](https://www.rtpcompany.com/products/color/special-effects/)

As for what grade of plastic, we could only make some educated guesses based on its use.